# Concourse Pipeline failing for simple pipleline

Tags: docker, concourse

Have done a new Concourse setup using docker-compose on sles linux.
docker 1.12.6 and concourse 3.2.1.
The pipeline (taken form starkanddwayne) are failing with following:

```
runc create: exit status 1: container_linux.go:264: starting container process 
caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: 
mounting \\\"/worker-state/3.2.1/assets/bin/init\\\" to rootfs \\\"/worker-
state/volumes/live/5b98b13d-8aea-42fa-6513-531f0b140cc0/volume/rootfs\\\" at 
\\\"/worker-state/volumes/live/5b98b13d-8aea-42fa-6513-
531f0b140cc0/volume/rootfs/tmp/garden-init\\\" caused \\\"open /worker-
state/volumes/live/5b98b13d-8aea-42fa-6513-
531f0b140cc0/volume/rootfs/tmp/garden-init: permission denied\\\"\""
```

The same works with concourse 3.0.1. Any clues why this would be failing.

Comment: Are you using `image_resource:` for all of your tasks?

Please look for any instances in which you are doing `image:`

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a bug in the kernel/filesystem driver. I've found 3 solutions:

1. Upgrade the kernel to 4.8 or newer.
2. Run the task with `privileged: true`
3. Ensure that the btrfs kernel module is loaded on the host system using `sudo modprobe btrfs` then run the worker using the btrfs filesystem driver `CONCOURSE_BAGGAGECLAIM_DRIVER: btrfs`.

Reference:
https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1230

Comment: Hi @DanielScott,

Comment: ugh. Just when I finally got my EL to upgrade to a v4 kernel, now I need to go a higher version they don't support?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve a (possibly very similar) issue (error was the same) by setting `CONCOURSE_RUNTIME=containerd`.

Comment: ran into this and this solution worked.  env: concourse deployed to arm k8s cluster via helm